# get image name from angularjs and use it in laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I was trying to use Laravel blade with AngularJS but both use the same markup when displaying variables so I changed the AngularJS variable using:

```js
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
```

But how do I use them both to get image name from AngularJS variable to blade

```
{{ HTML::image("images/<% image %>") }}
```

So how do I get the image?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Blade is a PHP templating engine. It is rendered before it ever hits the browser. Angular is JavaScript. It is never touched before the Blade is completely rendered.